# Is the multiplication of two complex numbers with $|z|=1$ a complex number with modulus 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

If we have two complex numbers $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|a|=1$ and $|b|=1$ is $|a\cdot b|=1$ as well?

I am trying to determine if the set $\left(\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\},\cdot\right)$ is a group.

I am not sure if it is closed under the binary operation $\cdot$. My intuition is that it is not closed under this operation. I may be misunderstanding something here, but any clarification and help would be helpful.

Comment: Yes!  And it is a very nice group :)

Comment: These are just points on the unit circle and multiplication would be the same as adding the angles together with reductions if the angles are large enough, or am I missing what the geometric interpretation here would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
|(x+iy)(u+iv)|^2 &=& |xu-yv+i(xv+yu)|^2 \\
&=& (xu-yv)^2+(xv+yu)^2 \\
&=& v^2 y^2+u^2 y^2+v^2 x^2+u^2 x^2 \\
&=& (x^2+y^2)(u^2+v^2) \\
&=& |x+iy|^2|u+iv|^2
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 5):

Yes! If $z=re^{2\pi i\theta}$, $z=se^{2\pi i\alpha}$ and $|z|=|w|=1$, then $r=s=1$ implies $zw=rse^{2\pi i(\alpha+\theta)}$, hence $|zw|=rs=1$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, $|zw|^2 = z\,w\,\overline{z\,w} = z\,w\,\overline z \, \overline w = z\,\overline z \, \,w\overline w = |z|^2\,|w|^2$.

In particular, $|z|=1=|w|$ implies $|zw|=1$.

Answer (score 2):

It is the image of the subgroup $i \mathbb{R} \le (\mathbb{C}, +)$ under the homomorphism $$\mathrm{exp} : (\mathbb{C}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{C}^{\times}, *)$$ so it is a subgroup as well. This is essentially the same as the polar form arguments above.